# How do I append lines to a file on the Ansible controller (collecting data from remote devices)

Tags: ansible

Please forgive my ignorance, I am still learning Ansible> Here is what I am trying to do:

-connect to device✔
-grab data✔ (json formated)
-de serialize (obtain lines for each json item in returns ✔
-write to a file ✔

for all the above I am using copy and a Jinja template

Now when I run that on multipe devices the copy module overwrites the results of the previous run. What is the module that will allow me to append the lines and work with the below Jinja template

```
{% for item in results.response %}
{% for value in item.values() %}{{ value }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}               
{{'\n'}}
{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Update:
I am not starting or stopping services not changing anything on the device, just collecting data (ex interafaces and their IPs). the result is something like this
device1,eth0,1.1.1.2
device1,eth1,1.1.1.3

Comment: What is the state you want to declare?

Comment: Not really following you ...what state are you talking about ? :-) (I apologize for my naive question)
I am just trying to dump data so that later I can import it (csv is the target format)

Comment: With Ansible you define a state. For example "service is started", "configuration file contains a specified line", "directory has specified permissions". I don't understand what state you want to declare.

Comment: nope I just collect data from network devices (take for example the ARP table), so these are read only scripts

Comment: What "*nope*" is supposed to mean? What state do you want to declare?

Comment: no state I am not starting or stopping services not changing anything on the device, just collecting data (ex interafaces and their IPs). the result is something like this
device1,eth0,1.1.1.2
device1,eth1,1,1,1,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a task that Ansible was really designed for.

If the content is multi-line as the template suggests, you can abuse `lineinfile` module (multi-line content will never match a line in the file, so it will keep adding the content to the end of the file):

```
- lineinfile:
    line: |-
      {% for item in results.response %}
      {% for value in item.values() %}{{ value }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}               
      {{'\n'}}
      {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    state: present
    dest: file.txt
```

---

Or you can call `shell: echo {{ template }} >> file`.

Comment: Yes I know Ansible was not designed for this but since it is possible why not. This is a surrogate solution till I learn how to deal with concurrency in SQL and multithreading in python (It looked easier and promissing since Ansible has good support via ntc-command for show commands and lots of templates so...

Comment: thanks a lot that worked
quick question how does this deal with the concurrent access to the file ? I used -f 5 and it worked ...I am going to test it soon on something bigger like 10 or 20 to see if it breaks

Comment: @MiniMe I think you could wrap the "lineinfile:" module in a "serial: 1" section (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size).

Comment: Actually it depends on how you structure your playbook I think ... mine had a task to append to the file after the info was collected so that took care of the whole thing because the append was serialized by the task